# Show javascript alert() after sending async email into a different class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multithreading, email

I have a VB ASP.NET aplication which at some point it has to send some emails (using System.Net.Mail).

I want to send them in background and once the sending finishes get some notification to know if the email was sent correctly or not (alert() the user). I tried to use SendAsync email, the problem is that in that way it freezes the UI, I also tried to encapsulate all the sending email method into a thread but after that the Httpcontext.current object is always null so I can't show the alert().

I have tried to search a solution around Stackoverflow but without any luck....

Comment: How are you creating the HTTP request that invokes the email sending code? Are you doing a full post back? Are you using AJAX?

Comment: I actually do something like this:
AddHandler SmtpClient.SendCompleted, AddressOf SendCompletedCallback
SmtpClient.SendAsync(Email, Nothing)

After that in SendCompletedCallback() I check if the email was sent correctly and using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler.GetType(), "show", "alert('"alert"');", True) I try to show the alert.

No, i'm not usin AJAX.

Comment: You need to make a request to your server via AJAX. Once the server has completed it's work asynchronously, it can return a result to you which you can use to notify the user etc. You don't need to think about multi-threading here, IIS will manage that for you. Have a look at the examples here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. You can use this to make a request to a web service or even to a code-behind method asynchronously.